# How to disable add-ons(flash) in firefox 16.0.1 using about:config or some configurable way

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, flash

We have some legacy codebase which uses a older version of firefox(16.0.1). I am struggling to find preferences to disable add-ons in firefox 16.0.1 Can some tell me the about:config configuration to disable add-ons for firefox 16.0.1 P.S:- Upgrading firefox is huge task, so avoiding it for now.

Comment: It's about:addons rather than about:config. Choose the ones you want to disable there. Flash is a plugin.

Comment: Hi Robert, How do we disable add-on using configuration ? What I am looking for, is there a way to disable on add-ons using config file ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `nsICategoryManager`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICategoryManager#Remarks

this code here disables currently active pdf's and will prevent future pdfs from working:

```
var CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/pdf';

// Update the category manager in case the plugins are already loaded.
let categoryManager = Cc['@mozilla.org/categorymanager;1'];
categoryManager.getService(Ci.nsICategoryManager).deleteCategoryEntry('Gecko-Content-Viewers', CONTENT_TYPE, false);

// Update pref manager to prevent plugins from loading in future
var stringTypes = '';
var types = [];

var PREF_DISABLED_PLUGIN_TYPES = 'plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types';
if (Services.prefs.prefHasUserValue(PREF_DISABLED_PLUGIN_TYPES)) {
    stringTypes = Services.prefs.getCharPref(PREF_DISABLED_PLUGIN_TYPES);
}
if (stringTypes !== '') {
    types = stringTypes.split(',');
}

if (types.indexOf(CONTENT_TYPE) === -1) {
    types.push(CONTENT_TYPE);
}
Services.prefs.setCharPref(PREF_DISABLED_PLUGIN_TYPES, types.join(','));
```